# Why allow deleted question to be marked as favorite?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, bookmarks

Recently I answered a question, and was closed as *Too Localized* by fellow users, so I was just playing with the deleted question and what I saw was that I was able to mark the question as favorite, why is that so? If the question is deleted than why favorite? It doesn't make any sense...Yea agreed that people with high reputation can view deleted questions but if the motive is to delete than all the controls should be disabled unless and until the post is undeleted

[Deleted Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083231/basic-c-hello-world-warning-when-using-printf/)

> Note: If you are running low on the rep you won't be able to see the
>   question

Comment: Why would people want to undelete that?

Comment: @Asad As some people state, questions cannot be deleted if it is having high voted answers, I don't know why it was deleted?

Comment: I think it was because the question had started to garner reopen votes. The question doesn't really have any valuable information IMO.

Comment: I can show you more idiotic questions than this, which are lying closed without any votes, but still aren't deleted..but this question affected my rep by 50, now that's what a lowest bounty cost...so it's not that cheap to be deleted:) you got my point?

Comment: +1 for revealing this, it's quite useful.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Ya still people downvote...

Comment: I'm just guessing that someone just disagreed with `but if the motive is to delete than all the controls should be disabled unless and until the post is undeleted`, which sounds like you want the behavior to change.

Comment: @Mr.Alien - The question was deleted because it contains a rather silly mistake (forgetting to include a header) with lots of duplicates. The very generic subject line didn't make it useful as a search target, so it has very little value (except for your rep). The new subject line is even worse, because the problem has nothing to do with printf specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted to follow the question to see if it's progressing toward becoming more suitable for restoration and reopening, you'd probably appreciate that behavior :)

As far as reputation is concerned, since 10k + users are the people that would naturally be interested in this progress, it makes sense to make it available to them. A user that could not see a deleted post couldn't take any action other than flagging if a substantial change was introduced, and its author *has* the ability to do that with even 1 reputation point.

While the use is very narrow, it's extremely handy in the scope of moderation.

Comment: What if user is running low on rep? He has anyways lost the question so why not the same rule for everyone? Or have a undelete review que instead of marking questions as favorite, moreover there is hardly any activity on deleted question, I guess no activity as the question is deleted, except the edit

Comment: I in fact sometimes use that feature when helping a user that pinged me via chat to see what they could do. It does have the side effect of sometimes cluttering up your favorites, but pruning mine every few weeks also serves as a reminder to revisit certain things. I guess some people find some utility in it, and if not .. well .. no need to use it :)

Comment: Also it doesn't even notify you that ok your favorite goes up by 1, as you usually see it in your account when you mark some question as favorite

Comment: That doesn't seem odd to me as I know I was marking a _deleted_ post, but I'm rather used to the system and can see how that would seem odd.

Comment: Hmm anyways, if that's what the reason you are using for, than it's kwel..as I thought why offer a favorite when the question is deleted anyways.. thanks for sharing it's alternate uses :p

Comment: A few other high rep users like the functionality as well. It can also be handy when a question goes through an unusually active close / open / delete / undelete cycle which isn't uncommon on more 'controversial' posts. My take is .. it doesn't _hurt_ anything to have it and using it is typically quite deliberate. I think it's probably an 'accidental' feature that just made sense to keep.